# neo4j - multiple optional matches

Tags: neo4j

I have the following neo4j database:
http://console.neo4j.org/?id=gkkmha

I then run the following query:

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:plays]->(instrument:Instrument {name: 'Drums'})
OPTIONAL MATCH (band:Band { name: 'bandname' })-[:genre]->(genre:Genre)<-[:likes]-(person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (band)-[:influenced]->(influence:Influence)<-[:influenced]-(person)
RETURN person.name, COLLECT(genre.name) as matched_genres, COLLECT (influence.name) as matched_influences, (count(genre)/4.0) as score
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I want to be able to find musicians who play the specified instrument but also have similar genre matches and influences to the band. So far I've got it working for matching genres and returning a list of those genres, but I can't make it do the same for influences. I want it to return a list of matching influences as well.

Ideally it'd also get the total number of genres and influences the band is associated with (though this is just a nice to have).

Current output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| person.name    | matched_genres    | matched_influences | score |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| "Robert Smith" | ["Soul","Motown"] | []                 | 0.5   |
| "Alex Smith"   | ["Soul"]          | []                 | 0.25  |
| "Mr Drummer"   | []                | []                 | 0.0   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows
54 ms
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you got there a typo, instead of `:influenced` try `:Influenced`

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[:plays]->(instrument:Instrument { name: 'Drums' })
OPTIONAL
MATCH (band:Band { name: 'bandname' })-[:genre]->(genre:Genre)<-[:likes]-(person)
OPTIONAL
MATCH (band)-[:Influenced]->(influence:Influence)<-[:Influenced]-(person)
RETURN person.name, COLLECT(genre.name) AS matched_genres, COLLECT(influence.name) AS matched_influences,(count(genre)/4.0) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC
```